# Website throws "PHP-GD not installed" but it is installed

Tags: php, php-gd

I wanted to make a Teamspeak Bannerbot, i downloaded a rar and now the website says, that php-gd isnt installed. After i installed it the same error came. Here you can see the index.php code, were it stops:

```
try {
    if (!function_exists('imagettftext')) {
        throw new Exception ('PHP-GD not installed >> http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php');
 }
```

Comment: Try `phpinfo()` and see if your `php-gd` extension shows up. It needs to be loaded in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: I have had like that situation . First you need to check php-gd installed path and insert that part in `php.ini` file and restart your apache

Comment: I editet into my php.ini file ```extension=php_gd2.dll``` (i delete the ; bevor the code) but the error dont go away